# Exponentiation - positional system based on three

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have a natural number x in the decimal system and natural number n in a ternary numeral system. How to calculate the value of x^n using the minimum number of multiplications?

I know the algorithm for a binary system and I was looking for an analogy, but I did not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need something like this:

```
function expbycubing(x, n): 

   //treat n = 0..2 cases here

   switch n % 3:
       0: return expbycubing(x * x * x, n shrt 1)    
       ///// note shift in ternary system  (tri)201 => (tri)020  
       1: return x * expbycubing(x * x * x, n shrt 1)
       2: return x * x * expbycubing(x * x * x, n shrt 1)
```

Working Delphi code

```
 function expbycubing(x, n: Integer): int64;
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('x: %d  n: %d', [x, n]));
    if n = 0 then Exit(1);
    if n = 1 then Exit(x);
    if n = 2 then Exit(x * x);
    case n mod 3 of
      0: Result := expbycubing(x * x * x, n div 3);
      1: Result := x * expbycubing(x * x * x, n div 3);
      2: Result := x * x * expbycubing(x * x * x, n div 3);
    end;
  end;

var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 12 to 12 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d: %d', [i, expbycubing(2, i)]));
end;
```

log:

```
x: 2  n: 12
x: 8  n: 4
x: 512  n: 1
12: 4096
```

Comment: Is the correct answer? Maybe I don't understand, but for example x = 2, n = tri(110) I have: x -> x^3 -> x^9 * x = x^10-> x^30 * x = x^31, but I should have x^12. Could you explain, please?

Comment: You unwinded recursion wrongly. When function returns from `return x * expbycubing(x * x * x, n shrt 1)`, x still has old value, so chain is x -> x^3 -> x^9 => here x^9 * x^3 => x^12.  I added execution log. The deepest level result 512 is multiplied by upper level x=8 to produce 4096